# Recursive formula for the integral $\int\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^k} dx$

Tags: integration

I need to derive a recursive formula for the integral $$ \int\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^k} dx\qquad(1)$$

I started from the assumption that $$x=tan(t) \qquad(2)$$ $$dx=sec^2(t) dt \qquad(3)$$ 
$$\frac{dx}{sec^2(t)}=dt$$

Subtitiution (2) into $1+x^2$:$$1+tan^2(t) = sec^2(t)\qquad(4)$$

Insert (3), (4) into (1)

$$I_k=\int\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^k} dx= \int\frac{1}{(sec^2(t))^k} \cdot sec^2(t) dt= \int (sec(t))^{-(2k-2)}dt = \int(cost)^{2k-2}dt$$

I know that I should apply integration by part to the element $$\int(cost)^{2k-2}dt$$but I don't know how to do it. I know the formula for this integration, but my tries bring crazy results. How to solve it?

Comment: You pull out one $\cos t $ and integrate by parts there. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae

Comment: Thank you @CalvinKhor ! I will try it!

Answer (score 5):

Let $I_k$ be your integral. Then, for $k>1$,
$$
I_k=\int \frac{1+x^2-x^2}{(1+x^2)^k}\,dx=
I_{k-1}-\int\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^k}\,dx=
I_{k-1}+\frac{1}{2}\int x\frac{-2x}{(1+x^2)^k}\,dx
$$
Now we can do by parts:
$$
\int x\frac{-2x}{(1+x^2)^k}\,dx=
x\frac{1}{k-1}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{k-1}}-
\frac{1}{k-1}\int\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{k-1}}\,dx
$$